# GKMatch with nearby players (Bluetooth, WiFI)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios7, game-center, gamekit

I'm using `GKMatchMakerViewController` to create a `GKMatch` instance between two players. This works okay, but it seems the connection is always established through the internet. The messages between the two devices need about 7 milliseconds to go through the wire.

Now I'd like to extend that functionality so that it prefers nearby players, i.e. players which can be reached over Bluetooth or which are on the same WiFi network. Ideally, the GUI would list all nearby players first, and only after them, the other players.

**Is that supported out-of-the-box, or do I need to write my own GUI for that?**

What classes and APIs do I need for that?